# Minimum number of solution of the function $f(x)=|x|^3+a|x|^2+b|x|+c$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My question:

How to find the minimum number of solution of the function $$f(x)=|x|^3+a|x|^2+b|x|+c$$ where $a$,$b$ and $c$ are positive real numbers.

How to tackle with this problem?

Comment: What about c? Is that imaginary?

Comment: I have edited. SRY

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If you want to solve $f(x)=0$, note all LHS terms are non-negative, and $c> 0$.  It never sums to zero...

Answer (score 1):

No real solution.Please note that $f(x)$ given is even.For $x\ge 0$ ,apply LMVT and you'll see that $f(x)>f(0)$.Since $ c\gt 0$,you conclude that $f(x)$ never becomes zero for any real $x$ .Similarly ,apply LMVT for $x\le 0 $ and you finally conclude-No real solution to $f(x)=0$!!

Comment: How does LMVT prove that $f(x)>f(0)$.Please explain.@kilimanjaro

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia,By LMVT,for $x\gt 0$,there exists $0<c \lt x$ such that $f'(c)=0 \implies  \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} =f'(c)=0 \implies f(x) \gt 0$